# Join Two Different Table

Tags: php, mysql

I tried subtracting 2 different table with the same "pocde" column. I have stated the code below, but it doesn't work for me. Any idea?

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
        productlist.*, 
        SUM(rreturn.total)-SUM(rreturn.total) as totals, 
        SUM(rsales.tax)-SUM(rreturn.tax) as tax
    FROM productlist
    LEFT JOIN rsales ON rsales.pcode = productlist.pcode
    LEFT JOIN rreturn ON rreturn.pcode = productlist.pcode
    GROUP BY pcode
    ORDER BY total ASC");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td style = "background-image:url(images/buts1.png)">'.($row['totals'].'</td>';   
            echo '<td style = "background-image:url(images/buts1.png)">'.($row['tax'].'</td>';              
            echo '</tr>';
    }
```

Comment: Won't `SUM(rreturn.total)-SUM(rreturn.total)` always return 0? Otherwise - you might have to explain what the actual problem is. What doesn't work?

Comment: Use functions with `mysqli_` prefix. Those with `mysql_` are deprecated.

Comment: How it doesn't work? Any errors? Post them if any

Comment: Seems like the first `rreturn.total` should be `rsales.total`

Comment: it walways return NULL

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this query because of the group by.
You could change your query like that:

```
SELECT pl.*, plagg.totals, plagg.tax
from productlist pl
inner join (
    SELECT 
        productlist.pcode, 
        SUM(rreturn.total)-SUM(rreturn.total) as totals, 
        SUM(rsales.tax)-SUM(rreturn.tax) as tax 
    FROM productlist
    LEFT JOIN rsales ON rsales.pcode = productlist.pcode
    LEFT JOIN rreturn ON rreturn.pcode = productlist.pcode
    GROUP BY productlist.pcode
) plagg on (plagg.pcode = pl.pcode)
```

Comment: im curious what is "pl" sir?

Comment: and im also curious what is "plag" sir sorry im just new t php

Comment: It's the subquery name. But this is SQL not PHP

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in the PHP code, because `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)` creates a **numeric** array. You would have to use `$row[0]`, `$row[1]` and so on. If you want to have an **associated** array as you try to use in your code (`$row['totals']` and so on), you either have to use

`mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)`

or you use

`mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`

. Please be aware that both is deprecated and you should really use PDO instead.